# $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n}$ is convergent implies $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n^{1+it}}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

We know that if $a_n\geq0$, then obviously, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{a_n}{n}$ converges implies $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{a_n}{n^{1+it}}$ converges for $t\in\mathbb R$. But if $a_n$ is not real, we can construct a Dirichlet series
$$D(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{a_n}{n^s}$$
which is convergent at $s=1$, but not convergent at $1+it$ for some $t\neq0$. In fact, let $p$ denote prime number. We know that the prime zeta function
$$P(s)=\sum_{p\,\in\mathrm{\,primes}} \frac{1}{p^s}=\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{3^s}+\frac{1}{5^s}+\frac{1}{7^s}+\frac{1}{11^s}+\cdots$$
which is convergent for all $1+it$ with $t\neq0$. Let
$$a_n=\begin{cases}
    1/p^i& n=p\,\, \text{is prime}\\
    0& \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$$
We have that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n^s}$ is convergent at $s=1$(even convergent for all $s\neq 1-i$), but divergent at $s=1-i$.

**Question** Restricts $a_n$ to be real but does not require $a_n$ to be non-negative. Can the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{a_n}{n}$ lead to the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{a_n}{n^{1+it}}$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$?.
Or can anyone give a counter example

Comment: Try $a_n = \Re(1/p^i)$

Comment: Look up Dirichlet eta function

Comment: @TravorLZH I know that the eta function is analytic in the whole complex plane, what I'm asking is a general result.

Comment: Let $a_n=\cos(nt)$

Comment: @HGF If complex sequence $b_n$ converges then $\Re(b_n)$ converges too

Comment: @TravorLZH My question is if the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{a_n}{n}$ lead to the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{a_n}{n^{1+it}}$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$? In general, not just example.  Or you can give a countable example.

Comment: @HGF What I gave is a counterexample

Comment: @TravorLZH But $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos n}{n^s}$ is convergent for all $\Re s>0$.

Comment: @reuns You mean $\sum\limits_{p}\frac{\cos\ln p}{p}$ is convergent? how to prove it? And  $\sum\limits_{p}\frac{\cos\ln p}{p^{1+i}}$ is not convergent. In other words，$\sum\limits_{p}\frac{(\cos(\ln p))^2}{p}$ is divergent.

Comment: @reuns  $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\log{n})}{n \cdot \log{n}}$ is convergent but $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(\cos(\log{n}))^2}{n \cdot \log{n}}$ is not convergent. Thanks alot for your answer.

Comment: @HGF It is true that $\sum_n{\cos n/n^s}$ converges whenever $s>0$, but it is not true that it converges for all $\Re(s)>0$.

Comment: @TravorLZH I think $\sum_n \cos n/n^s$ converges for all $\Re s>0$, because the partial sums $\sum_{n\leq x}\cos n$ is bounded.

Comment: Dirichlet test requires the other factor to be monotonically decreasing to zero instead of something nonreal

Comment: @TravorLZH You can use Abel's summation.

Comment: You are right, I should have said $\cos(t\log n)$ instead